# Gnuplot complain with ')' expected when array is not defined at specific line

Tags: gnuplot

I am using a gnuplot script that yields an error when the last line of the script is executed. I don't see any issue with this line. The error is:  ***')' expected***. If a move the line ***array M_x_N[numRecord]*** before the line
***stats N using (M_x_N[int($0+1)] = N[int($0+1)]*M[int($0+1)]) name "M_x_N" nooutput***
there is no error. What wrong?

I am using the QT terminal, gnuplot 5.4 patch level 8. OS is Windows 10.

The script is:

```
reset session
set encoding utf8
set datafile separator comma
cd 'C:\Users\smallz4'
corpusFile = "lz4_silicia_corpus.txt_4096.csv"
stats corpusFile nooutput
numRecord = STATS_records
chunkSize = numRecord-15.0
bias = 2048.0

array M[numRecord]
array N[numRecord]
array M_x_N[numRecord]

stats corpusFile using (M[int($0+1)] = $1) name "M" nooutput
stats corpusFile using (N[int($0+1)] = $2) name "N" nooutput

stats N using (M_x_N[int($0+1)] = N[int($0+1)]*M[int($0+1)]) name "M_x_N" nooutput
```

Comment: Please always provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including minimal data for copy & paste and testing. If it's not an obvious typo or wrong syntax, and if we don't have your data and directory structure, it might become time consuming to reproduce your error message.

Comment: Which is the script you actually executed? Before assigning values to an array you have to specify the size of the array. So, of course, `array M_x_N[numRecord]` must be **before** `stats N using (M_x_N[int($0+1] = ... `. Maybe I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was struggling a while to find out what's going on. For a reason which I don't yet understand, it seems the name of your final array causes the error.

`help variables` says:

> Valid names are the same as in most programming languages: they must
> begin with a letter, but subsequent characters may be letters, digits,
> or "_".

So, `M_x_N` should be a valid variable or array name. At least, I haven't yet found a statement that says `_` is not allowed for array names.

With the following minimal, **complete** example, I can reproduce your error. And now, I think I understand what you mean.
Apparently, the sequence of the array definitions and the `stats` commands are important.

**Script:** (this script will fail with your error)

```
### strange behaviour with setting arrays and using stats
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   10
 2   20
 3   30
 4   40
EOD

stats $Data u (c=$0+1) nooutput   # get the number of rows into c

array M[c]
array M_x_N[c]

stats $Data u (M[int($0+1)] = $1) name "M" nooutput
stats $Data u (M_x_N[int($0+1)] = $2) name "M_x_N" nooutput
### end of script
```

However, if you change the sequence to the following, it will work.

```
array M[c]
stats $Data u (M[int($0+1)] = $1) name "M" nooutput

array M_x_N[c]
stats $Data u (M_x_N[int($0+1)] = $2) name "M_x_N" nooutput
```

Another version with the original sequence, i.e. all array definitions first and then all `stats` commands will work as expected, if you change the name of the array  `M_x_N` to `MxN`.

```
array M[c]
array MxN[c]

stats $Data u (M[int($0+1)] = $1) name "M" nooutput
stats $Data u (MxN[int($0+1)] = $2) name "MxN" nooutput
```

So, my conclusion would be that the underscores in `M_x_N` somehow mess up the `stats` command. I would consider this a bug or maybe someone else can explain.

Comment: I will report a bug and see what the developers say. I will keep the thread posted. - Sorry for the struggle with the example.

Comment: @GuyB don't worry, I'm happy to learn and understand new things ;-) Ok, will you add it on https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/ or should I?

Comment: Please do it. After all, you did the example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird one. I understand what is happening but I don't have an easy fix or work-around other than to use a different name scheme for your variables.

The problem is that when gnuplot sees the command

```
`stats $Data u (<anything>) name "M"`
```

it knows that the stats command will create a bunch of variables named `M_*`, in this case
M_records = 4
M_invalid = 0
M_headers = 0
M_blank = 0
M_blocks = 1
M_outofrange = 0
M_columns = 2
M_mean = 2.5
and so on.  In preparation for this it deletes all existing variables that match the pattern `M_*`.  Unfortunately that includes the previously declared array `M_x_N`.

If I recall correctly, the rationale for deleting potentially conflicting variables was that failure of the `stats` command is considered a non-fatal error.  Some scripts used the existence of one of these variables to test whether a previous `stats` command had succeeded or not.  The idea was that `stats` would delete them on entry, then create (or possibly re-create) them after successful execution. So if `STATS_records` (or in this case `M_records`) did not exist or was undefined after executing the `stats` command then the command must have failed.  Furthermore, if a script blindly uses one of these variables to make a plot or further calculations then delete-on-failure prevents generating an incorrect plot or calculation using leftover values from an earlier successful `stats` command on a different data source.

One could complain that deleting ***all*** variables matching the name pattern is over-kill; why doesn't the program limit itself to deleting just the admittedly long list of variable names it will create? Fair enough. But even so you would hit the same problem if instead of creating an array named `M_x_N` you created one named `M_sumxy` or any of the 30+ other names that the `stats` command can over-write.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That makes sense. A bug should be opened for follow-up with the developers. And please do document this limitation. At least a workaround exists and we know in which context this would happen.